# Do nothing if route filter fails check

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have a Route Filter that I want to essentially do nothing if the filter fails the check.

I'm basically doing a restricted area, but I don't want to redirect if it fails, I'd rather the user stay right where they are at.

```
Route::group(array("prefix"=>"protected", "before"=>"level:3"),function(){ ... }

Route::filter('level', function($route, $request, $value)
{
    if(Auth::user()->level < $value) // do nothing
}
```

Unfortunately, doing nothing results in access to the page. `Doing Route::back()` seems to work, except that there's not a page refresh where one isn't necessary and could confuse the user. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You have to understand that if you are doing the common form POST (or even GET) to send the data, you already did something big: you have sent a request and you cannot take it back. The page where your user was is already gone and he's now in a new page. You have to at least render your view again:

```
return View::make('my.very.same.view');
```

It may blink/flash, and it will looks like something has happened to page.

So if you need, in case of exception or error, stay in the same page, you have to send your data using Ajax and if it's all right with your data, do whatever you need to do.